# Using a checkbox to filter a Boolean on table view. Inherited (relation) datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I bind a checkbox to filter a query in a table view? The datasource contains the field "active" and it is an inherited (relation) to the pages main datasource. I could create another datasource that filters on a parameter that is bound to the checkbox but this returns all results in the table do to losing the inherited (relation). Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to keep the inherited relation if possible.

Comment: A value binding of `@datasource.query.filters.YourBooleanField._equals` doesn't work for you?

Comment: That is how I expected to accomplish it however the checkbox widget lacks the query identifier.

Comment: If you could maybe explain your setup a bit more then maybe we can find a solution. I think I might be missing something in your setup in regards to the table relation vs datasource inheritance for the widget itself.

Comment: Table Units
Table Resident (Relation to Units) many residents to one unit.

There is a list view on the units, when a list item is selected the related residents are displayed in a table. I'm trying to add a checkbox(toggle) to display only the active residents when checkbox is false. When the checkbox is true, display all the related resident records.

The checkbox widget does not have the query option like a textbox or other widgets would.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. So since your residents list is set to ‘Units: Residents (Relation)’ you cannot use a query on that list unfortunately because App Maker does not support direct relation filtering. There is a feature request for that functionality but it has not been addressed. The workaround is to create a separate Residents datasource that gets prefiltered on the related units Id and reloads each time a different item is selected in units. This is actually quiet easy to set up.